# AngularJS: ng-class - Using multiple classes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I am new to AngularJS.

I want to add a class to the second column based on it's value. Example: I want add the class 'positive' if the value is > 0 and class 'negative' when it is < 0.

What I am currently using:

```
<td data-ng-class="{positive: $index==1 && {{values}} > 0 , negative:{{values}} < 0 && $index==1 }" ng-repeat="values in portfolio" >{{values}}</td>
```

Now, this seems to be working (see image):

[image]

But, I am getting the following in my console:

Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$parse/syntax?p0=%26&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%7D%5D&p2=26&p3=%7Bpositive%3A%20%24index%3D%3D1%20%26%26%20S%26P500%20%3E%200%20%2C%20negative%3AS%26P500%20%3C%200%20%26%26%20%24index%3D%3D1%20%7D&p4=%26P500%20%3E%200%20%2C%20negative%3AS%26P500%20%3C%200%20%26%26%20%24index%3D%3D1%20%7D
    at Error ()
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:6:449
    at Xa.throwError (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:155:346)
    at Xa.consume (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:156:325)
    at Xa.object (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:164:115)
    at Xa.primary (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:154:482)
    at Xa.unary (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:161:240)
    at Xa.multiplicative (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:160:480)
    at Xa.additive (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:160:325)
    at Xa.relational (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:160:204)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<td data-ng-class="{positive: $index==1 && values > 0, negative:values < 0 && $index==1 }" ng-repeat="values in portfolio" >{{values}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, awesome. No errors now. I will accept this as an answer after the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `{{values}}` to `values`

```
<td data-ng-class="{positive: $index==1 && values > 0 , negative:values < 0 && $index==1 }" ng-repeat="values in portfolio" >{{values}}</td>
```